# Comparing arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am attempting to determine if any item from a list of values is present in an array column in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE array IN (array)
```

I have this working using the && operator and a manually constructed array literal:

```
SELECT id, data FROM things WHERE '{"value", "other"}' && (array_column)
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Are you really using 9.2 already? (which is not yet released)

Comment: I am using the current 9.2 dev release, yes

Answer (score 3):

This is a quite good way, what do you mean by a better way?

There is one thing which could be done some other way, you can create the array using `ARRAY[...]` like this:

```
select ARRAY['a', 'b'] && '{"a", "c"}';
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the two versions?

Comment: In my case, I get a typing error when comparing using the ARRAY syntax